# How to force value initialization for POD types in Visual C++ without changing code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Is there any way to force initialization of pod types to `0\false\nullptr` in *Visual C++* release mode?

To be more specific, I don't want to change my code, just have it compiled with pod types initialized to `0\false\nullptr.`

I want this because I want our system to be deterministic.

Comment: It's important to understand that a C++ compiler has multiple stages. The statement `int i` inside a function doesn't even reach the code generation stage. If you would need to implement this feature in a compiler, you would need to rewrite the code on the fly. The worst is probably `new int[expr]` expressions, with constructors a good second.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, value initialization will do this.

```
struct pod {
    int a, b;
    char c;
    double d;
};

pod myPod = pod(); // Value-initialized, all members are 0.
```

C++11 will also allow you to assign default values in the class definition, but Visual Studio doesn't support this yet.

```
struct pod { 
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    char c = 0;
    double d = 0.0;
};

pod myPod; // All members would be initialized to 0.
```

Comment: Problem is, I have a large codebase and I dont want to rewrite code.

Comment: @ViktorSehr: So you want your code to behave differently from what it does now **without** changing it ?

Comment: I think the best you can do is overloading `operator new` to zero-initialize all dynamically allocated memory, but you're probably out of luck for PODs allocated on the stack.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you're suggesting. I explicitly stated it will only work on dynamically allocated PODs.